# Extract river nodes from linestring

Tags: python, geopandas, linestring

I want to extract the coordinates of river confluences.

I have a shapefile of rivers in a watershed. I want to get the coordinates of each point where a river joins another.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

river = gpd.read_file('./data/river_sota.shp')
```

[image]

I tried intersection but this operation only works with different shapefiles.

```py
river.intersection(river)
```

I want to find the intersection within the same shapefile.

Comment: Please describe how far you have got and include the relevant code. Have you successfully loaded your shapefile as a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame?

Comment: Yes river = gpd.read_file('./data/river_sota.shp')

Comment: What have you tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed.

Comment: river.intersection(river) but this is between different shapefiles. I want to find the intersection within the same shapefile

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? So one river is one line segment? One river cant be two individual segments joined together start/end to start/end?

Comment: Individual segments

Comment: How many are there?

Comment: 5361 individual segments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working with my river data:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/rivers.shp')
    
s = pd.Series(df.geometry.values, index=df.index).to_dict() #Create a dictionary with index as key and geometry as value
   
intersections = []
for i in itertools.combinations(s, 2): #For all pairwise combination of river indixes (dont do this with very large datasets..) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092474/get-all-pairwise-combinations-from-a-list
    i1, i2 = i
    if s[i1].intersects(s[i2]): #If they intersect
        intersections.append([i1, i2, s[i1].intersection(s[i2])]) 
        #Store their indexes and intersection geometry (should be points) as a list of lists
        #For example:
        #[[12, 20, <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7f7ed18968b0>],
        # [12, 21, <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7f7ed1896e80>],
        # [13, 14, <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7f7ed1896fa0>]]

#Create a dataframe from the list
dfinter = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data=intersections, columns=['first_line','second_line','geometry']), geometry='geometry', crs="EPSG:3006")
dfinter.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/river_intersections.gpkg') #I couldnt export as shapefile because
    #Some of the intersections were multipoints, geopackage worked.
```

[image]

Comment: RuntimeError: GDAL Error: Attempt to write non-point (MULTIPOINT) geometry to point shapefile. 
 
 Failed to write record: {'id': '30', 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'first_line': 3, 'second_line': 648}, 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPoint', 'coordinates': ((3.1417110090308236, 10.56099587036708), (3.1417150506463645, 10.561003192402628))}}

Comment: I get this error while saving the file

Comment: See my comment at the end: "I couldnt export as shapefile because
    Some of the intersections were multipoints, geopackage worked." If you need shapefile I suggest to explode the geopackage in QGIS and save as shape

Comment: Alright I will deal with that issue. Thank you!

Comment: test = dfinter.loc[30][2]

Comment: [(Point(pt.x, pt.y)) for pt in test]

Comment: This code converts shapely.geometry.MultiPoint ti shapely.geomety.Point

Comment: How can I add a if df['geometry'] is MultiPoint use code to replace by Point?

Comment: I can try tonight, I dont have access to my data now

Comment: Okay if it works and you have lists of Point instead of MultiPoints you can then use DataFrame.explode to get individual rows instead of list of Points